# Ruby HTTPRequest takes 60+ seconds to facebook oauth server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth

I'm trying to set up a manual oauth flow to sign my users in via facebook, pretty standard fare.

I have the redirect working properly and it sends the code to my callback function. I then have to exchange my code for an access_token with facebook. That is taking 60+ seconds if it doesn't just completely time out. I've done this exact same functionality multiple times before and have had no issues. Other sites will respond instantly while facebook for some reason takes 60+ seconds. Keep in mind that this same code ran in my production server's rails console works instantly. If I do an equivalent request via curl it also works instantly. This issue is ONLY happening in the Rails Console on my local machine. I tested with RestClient and HTTParty and got the same results.

```
url = "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/oauth/access_token?client_id=#{CLIENT_ID}&redirect_uri=http://127.0.0.1:3000/facebook_oauth_redirect&client_secret=#{CLIENT_SECRET}&code={#CODE}"
response = RestClient.get(url, :content_type => 'application/json', :accept => :json)
```

I can not figure out what is going wrong. I suspected maybe something with SSL but I can get responses from other https sites without issue. I got it down to the TCPSocket itself taking 60+ seconds to be opened.

```
s = TCPSocket.new 'graph.facebook.com', 443
```

That takes about 75 seconds to open while other sites are in a fraction of that time. My coworker confirmed he can open the TCPSocket instantly. I'm all out of ideas at the moment so any advice would be welcome.

EDIT: Seems that the issue is probably my new wireless router I got a few weeks ago. I hooked my Mac up to my iPhone hotspot and it worked instantly.

Comment: Your `url` has a random `}` at the end. Is that a mistake? `CLIENT_SECRET` and `CODE` are not interpolated there. Have you tried this on other machines? Maybe you're being throttled. Maybe your Ruby installation is broken and upgrading Ruby would help.

Comment: Sorry, in my rush to censor some of those values I just replaced them with constants. Maybe I'll try a different version of ruby, I dont think I'm being throttled considered I'm requesting like once every 5 minutes, if that. Besides, it works with curl.

Comment: Changing the version of ruby did not solve anything, just an update.

Comment: Do normal HTTP connections to other things work quickly? How about HTTPS?

Comment: It was bizzare. HTTP connections and HTTPs connections to other sites had no issue, just the graph.facebook api and only in the rails console. If I put the get request in the browser or in curl it worked, use RestClient or HTTParty and it fails.

Regardless I reset my wireless router, power cycled it once or twice, then spoofed my MAC address. That seemed to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution ended up being my wireless router or modem, not entirely sure what. Money is on the router since I upgraded a few weeks ago.

Power cycling wasn't helping so I spoofed the MAC address and that seemed to solve the issue after a power cycle.

Not really sure what the issue was considering that everything in browser/curl was working fine, the issue was just rails console (which the spoofing fixed).